# es_extended error: Attempt to call a table value (field ?)

Tags: function, lua, fivem

So this error pops up in server console F8 in FiveM.

> ```
> Attempt to call a table value (field ?)
> ```

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

[image: Screenshot of the corresponding line]

Im not very informed in the way how fivem core resources work. Can you help me out!
Thank you!

Comment: You would need to check the code for more information.

Comment: i share an image on line 1040 of the code

Comment: Please send the code as code, not images. Btw they got the same error here: https://forum.cfx.re/t/solved-servercallback-by-esx/1065332/3, is this error related?